# получить аватарку vk api без авторизации

Tags: vkontakte-api

Есть ли способ вытащить аватарку с ВК без авторизации? Суть в том что нужна только аватарка с ВК посетителя сайта (для отображения). Не каких других данных не нужно.

Comment: Если интересует аватарка конкретного текущего посетителя, это автоматически неизбежно означает какую-либо авторизацию

Comment: API вконтакте не позволит. Можете попробовать парсить html содержимое страницы пользователя, но я не уверен, что вк отображает все страницы неавторизованным пользователям. А вообще не вижу причины избегать авторизации в вк апи.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Способ есть. Если известен `id` пользователя, то некоторую информацию о нём (в т.ч. ссылку на аватарку) можно узнать без авторизации с помощью [`https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=<user_id>`](https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=<user_id>). Эта страница возвращает XML с информацией о пользователе.

```py
import requests

requests.get("https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=<user_id>")
```

Далее остаётся только распарсить XML из ответа и получить ссылку на аватарку. Например, с помощью `BeautifulSoup`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

user_id = 1

r = requests.get(f"https://vk.com/foaf.php?id={user_id}")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
avatar_url = soup.find("foaf:image", {"ya:primary": "yes"}).get("rdf:about")
print(avatar_url)
```